# Why my DomPDF wont render image from my HTML?

Tags: php, dompdf

I am making a PDF in my PDFGeneratorService, all works good except that image isnt being rendered. I have changed the image to jpeg format, I have added a chroot, I have added

```
'dompdf' =>[
        'enable_remote' =>true,
    ],
```

to my app config
But nothing seems to render the image : `<img src="{{ asset('logo/Logo.jpg') }}" alt="" class="">`
, heres the code

````
namespace App\Services;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PDFGeneratorService

{

    protected $dompdf;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->dompdf = new Dompdf();
    }
    public function generateReceiptPDF($receipt){
        $options = new Options();
        $options->set('default', 'Arial');
        $options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
        $options->setChroot("/public/assets");
        $this->dompdf->setOptions($options);
        $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        $html = view('pdf.receipt', ['receipt' => $receipt]);
        $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $directory = public_path('storage/temp');
        
        $filename = 'receipt_' . $receipt->created_at->format('YmdHis') . '.pdf';
        File::ensureDirectoryExists($directory);
       
        $pdfPath = Str::finish($directory, '/') . ltrim($filename);
      
        
        file_put_contents($pdfPath, $this->dompdf->output());
        return $pdfPath;
    }
}```
Please help, thanks in advance!
````

Comment: Try temporarily adding `width` and `height` attributes to the `img` tag. Seems that I've had issues with images not appearing in the past if nothing was set. Maybe at least the `width` may be enough, but that has been my experience.

Comment: Solved! I have just used base64 encoding, since DomPDF has troubles getting the image, it gets it when its encoded. Anyways thanks

Comment: No worries here, glad you found the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image into base64 string then place it in `src` of `img` tag.

DOM PDF does not allow to render images directly.